# Return JSON as javascript object

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-autocomplete

I am using jQuery-Autocomplete for one of my forms: https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete

I am receiving an error because I believe my response is in the wrong format.

The response from the server must be in this format:

```
"suggestions": [
    { "value": "United Arab Emirates", "data": "AE" },
    { "value": "United Kingdom",       "data": "UK" },
    { "value": "United States",        "data": "US" }
]
```

My response looks like: (It's missing "suggestions:")

```
[
    { "value": "United Arab Emirates", "data": "AE" },
    { "value": "United Kingdom",       "data": "UK" },
    { "value": "United States",        "data": "US" }
]
```

My action looks like:

```
[AjaxRequest]
public JsonResult UserLookup(string query)
{
    var users = _userRepo
        .GetUsers(query)
        .Select(u => new { Value = u.UserId, Data = u.FullName });

    return Json(users, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Ajax Request:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.requestor-autocomplete').autocomplete({
            serviceUrl: '@Url.Action("userlookup", "pir")',
            minChars: 3
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any suggestions on how I can format the response from the server correctly?

Comment: Can't remember the exact syntax but its something like return Json(new {suggestions: users}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: I'll give that a shot.  I know it's something simple.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @SkelDave I was able to figure out what I needed to do.  I updated the last line in my action to: `return Json(new { Suggestions = users }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`